# rbenv: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby. I have installed the latest version of ruby,rvm & homebrew on mac OSX El Capitan.

Installed RVM by

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

I get the following warning after the installation is complete and i am yet to do anything about it,

```
WARNING: You have '~/.profile' file, you might want to load it,
to do that add the following line to '/Users/abcde/.bash_profile':

  source ~/.profile
```

I am getting the command not found error when executing commands with rbenv

```
rbenv rehash
rbenv: command not found
```

My .bash_profile looks like

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Users/abcde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/GEM:$PATH
```

Ruby version is,

```
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15].
```

which -a ruby returns

```
/Users/abcde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

When i check the path with

```
echo $PATH
```

gives the following output

```
/Users/abcde/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/Users/abcde/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin:/Users/abcde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/abcde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/GEM:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Users/abcde/.rvm/bin
```

Seems to be a path issue but i can't figure out what it is or how to fix it.

Thank you

Comment: You install [rvm](https://rvm.io/) but tried to run [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv). This is different managers.

Comment: For what you need it? I run Ruby, but RBENV doesn't work for me either. Never had a problem. Isn't RBENV similar to RVM?

Comment: If you're installing Ruby for the first time, you can just run `brew install ruby`. If you definitely need a version manager, understand that RVM and Rbenv are incompatible tools. One needs to be uninstalled to use the other. I prefer rbenv, but if you're sticking with RVM, read the warning message and do what it says. It's just telling you to add a line to the end of a file.

Comment: Thank you for the input Mr Max. Ruby seems to be working fine.Am not too experienced at this time to decide which one i would prefer rvm/rbenv so i will stick with what is working for now. I was able to start the server and was also able to get a test website running as well as some ruby scripts from tutorials. So to clear the warning off i just have to append `source ~/.profile` and remove `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` in my bash_profile ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rbenv and rvm are both tools to manage ruby versions. They behave slightly different. rbenv does need you to rehash its 'shims' for you to pick up the current binaries. rvm does it a bit different. As you are using rvm, just omit the rbenv part.

rvm will pickup the correct ruby version from `.ruby-version` file and (if you want to have one) the gemset from `.ruby-gemset`

As you pasted the output of `ruby -v` and the path, everything looks to be working for you. You are all set and ready to go! :-) Just omit rbenv stuff.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Mr Milan. I will omit the rbenv stuff. I have the following entry in my .bash_profile file   `eval "$(rbenv init -)"`. Is it safe to remove it manually or is it a must to uninstall rbenv ? I am getting `rbenv: command not found` when my terminal starts up and on every output when i am using sublime Text 3 with python.

Comment: It is safe to remove. It should probably be replaced with ```source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm``` as per [rvm installation documentation](https://rvm.io/rvm/install#installation)